# Remove sub string vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, replace, substring

How can i remove `ing` from a word if it shows continuity:
ie,

Remove `ing` if words like

- playing
- dancing
- crying
- eating
- imitating

will not Remove `ing` if words like

- sing
- wing
- swing

I know that if i want to remove `ing` from a word means i can use any of the following methods:

Method 1:

```
Dim op As String
Dim input As String = "playing"
Dim pattern = "ing\.?|ING\.?"
op = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "") 'play
```

Method 2:

```
Dim op As String
Dim input As String = "playing"
op = input.Replace("ing", "")
```

My **Q**uestion is that is it possible to check whether the word show continuity? if yes then remove `ing` from the word

Comment: regex don't know whether the remainig string after removing `ing` would give a meaningfull word or not. But you could set the limit, like remove the substring `ing` only if the preceding chars except space must be atleast 3.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not enough to do this kind of analysis. I would suggest querying an online service (such as [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/)) to know whether the word is a continuous form or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use "$" sign at the end of your pattern which means that the ing should be at the end of word. Since there is no English word with the ing at the end of it that means other than continuity, you can use this pattern:

```
Dim pattern = "\w+ing\.?$|\w+ING\.?$"
```

Hope this helps